# Question sorting in Area 51

Tags: bug, status-completed, questions, area-51, sorting

If you're scrolling a site proposal with more than one page of example questions, sometimes the order is not consistent, so you see the same question again when moving to another page (and presumably miss some other question).

This happens frequently when question scores are changing due to you or someone else voting on them.

---

### Edit:

I've also noticed that questions are sorted by default by "my votes" or "all votes". Where is exactly that randomness the SE staff has been talking so much about lately?!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a bug.  If you want to work through all the questions, then use the "votes" or "newest" tabs.  You can't really fix this the way you want, because the current listing of the off/on topic has to have the undesired behaviour, since we *want* to see which are so far considered closest to being in the top 10.